# python import function picking wrong file with same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-requests

I have 3 files with same names in different directory. I want to run all of the files in the loop so what i do is like  I am changing the sys.path = new_path in every iteration and then do the import of the file but i donot know what's wrong with the import its always running the last file. Thanks in advance.

```
  import os
import sys
import importlib.util
import distutils.sysconfig as sysconfig
sys.path.insert(0, sysconfig.get_python_lib(standard_lib=1))



currpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
# print(currpath)
i=0
for folders in os.listdir(currpath):
    i = i+1
    print(folders)
    file_name = "a.py"
    new_path = currpath+"/"+folders+"/"+file_name
    if os.path.isfile(new_path):
       print("hello")
       sys.path = new_path
       import a
       a.fun()
```

Comment: You might want to use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly) instead.

Comment: But i still want to know the issue why it is so. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Aren't you just overwriting the imported 'a' module at every iteration of the loop?

Comment: `import` caches the module so if you try to import it again it will just return the first one it imported.

Comment: but i am also overwriting the  "sys.path = new_path" also its printing the last one always. Just showing you the structure of my directory.

A-
 a.py
B-
 a.py
C-
 a.py
main.pyT

It's always printing the third file. Why so? I am overwriting my sys.path . I have debugged it. sys.path is correct, but still it's always going into a.py of C directory. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @vishalsha95570 It's not so simple. I'd suggest you to read up on Python's import mechanism, specifically finders and import hooks: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#finders-and-loaders

Comment: okay thank for the time, i will.